# A horizontal selector for tips

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-view

I'm looking to implement tips into my app, and I really like this style of selector I'm attaching here (it's a screenshot from an iOS app). Is there something equivalent to this sort of horizontal selector on the Android side? Or should I just be squashing buttons or other views together?

Thanks for the help, I have also considered using a spinner instead, but I like this sort of style of all the options shown at one time in one line.

[image]

Comment: It is not same but check the [MaterialButtonToggleGroup](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Button.md#toggle-button-1)

Comment: Hey, thanks for telling me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. They are called [Chips](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/Chip).
Specifically you probably referring to a [ChipGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/ChipGroup).
and there's a guide and some examples on how to use them [here](https://www.material.io/develop/android/components/chip/)
They are rather new (might be the reason you were having trouble finding the name of what you are looking for) but they are included in the google material library so that provides support for older android versions.

Comment: I haven't seen this before, thanks for telling me about it. For now I just used a horizontally oriented RadioGroup with custom drawable backgrounds, but this looks good.